# HTML tags IE9 not rendering properly

Tags: html, tags, internet-explorer-9

hi all i got a strange behavior .

i got this html structure in Chrome :

```
<div id=xxxx>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;overflow:hidden"></div>
    <div id="id_xxx" class="cccddsw" style="left:1500px"></div>
    ........
</div>
<table style=width:100%;backgrou...........position:relative id="">...</table>
```

i got some JavaScript animations for this divs to appear or disappear it depends on which button you click but in IE9 and below i get the first div with `id  = xxxxx` nested inside the table and i got the code front of me which is not the case . in IE10 it renders perfect like Chrome why this is happening . if anyone can help will appreciate thanks.

Comment: Impossible to debug without the relevant JS code or a working JSfiddle demonstration.

Comment: the problems is not the js  is the divs uperlevel of table go inside table it self doesnt happen in chrome or ie10 , the js is only make the visibilty of those divs to true or false nothing more , so the problem is why these divs goes inside the table .

Comment: You should style in css style sheet. Also i believe the problem is with the position attributes

Comment: Embrace your table style inside "".

Comment: the code above is only a sample i know its missing quotes, its relivant like i said all good i created the html with VS2012 using resharper so its working in chome and ie10 not ie9 or 8 or 7 .thanks

Comment: Nothing ? any help suggestion why divs goes as child for a table and its not the case , divs are above table in same level

Comment: Have you run your code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). It sounds like there might be some invalid markup in your page. Use the validator and fix any errors it reports.

Comment: cant use it as the page is in localhost

Comment: Actually you can use W3C Validator even when it is localhost. Look at the [Validation by Direct Input](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) section.